# Count number of possibilities to split a string into 3 parts with at least 1 vowel

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a different version of "Split into Words" or "Word Break" problem in dynamic programming. I know the "Word Break" but couldnt adapt it into following problem:

**You are given a text (max 200 characters) from a file and required to split the word into 3 parts, each will contain minimum 1 vowel.**

For example, for the following text: bcaeiouxtz , we can have 6 possibilities:

bca eio uxtz
bca ei ouxtz
bca e iouxtz
bcae io uxtz
bcae i ouxtz
bcaei o uxtz

I would like to write dynamic programming approach in which I will be able to count how many possibilities I can have.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: `I would like to write dynamic programming approach` And what is the question?

Comment: Sounds like a great project. **Go ahead and write it**, come back when you get stuck and have a **specific** question and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: I would like to use a 2D array in which row values will be characters and column values will be 1, 2 and 3. In each row, when we see a vowel we increase the value as a[i][j] = a[i-1][j]+a[i][j] assuming that the number of possibilities added. But this solution doesnt give always correct output.

Comment: Do you want to produce all the possible splits, or just count them? If you only need to count them, there is a linear time solution with constant storage requirement.

Comment: I need only count no need to display them all

Answer (score 1):

No need for dynamic programming. Once you've located the vowels, the first is necessary in the first word, the last in the third. So you just have to enumerate the factors in between, `aeiou` -> `eio`, so in the middle you can have `e`, `ei`, `eio`, `i`, `io`, `o`. Two loops are sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, compared to dynamic programming, seems very simple